# Java variable scope in if statement

Tags: java, syntax-error

I received a compilation error for the following code:

```
if(true)
    int a = 10;
else
    int b = 20;
```

If I change it to the following code, then there is no compilation error:

```
if(true) {
    int a = 10;
}
else {
    int b = 20;
}
```

Why is the first syntax wrong, and from what language standard?

Comment: Is it not? Without the braces, you're conditionally declaring a variable (which is not allowed)? With the braces, you're declaring a block scope variable?

Comment: `/tmp/java_fCmGzo/HelloWorld.java:18: error: variable declaration not allowed here
        int b = 20;`

Comment: After doing some testing, it seems JVM doesn't like having variable declarations inside an `if-else` without braces. I'm sure someone could go more in-depth with this, but my *guess* is the scope can't be resolved. `System.out.println()` works without braces.

Comment: @DrewKennedy It wouldn't be so crazy if declaring variables inside `if-else` without braces isn't allowed. You're setting a variable which you can never use.

Comment: @Daniel I was just thinking that too. If you're allowed only one line of code after the `if`, declaring a variable wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @almasshaikh I don't know if this is a duplicate. The fact that the answer to that question is the same as the answer to this question doesn't necessarily mean they are the same question.

Comment: @Daniel See OP there as well has same issue. The only difference here OP is defining int whereas There OP had Main class. So it is a duplicate and with same question.

Comment: @almasshaikh:  This isn't looking like a dupe.  It may be similar, but it'd make sense to keep the semantics of `if` and `for` distinct.

Comment: @Daniel The language designers could have decreed that this is legal and declares the variable in the scope outside the `if`, so that it could be used later.  But this would make the code difficult to read and invite more coding errors, so that's a good enough reason for Java to disallow it.  Of course that means that JavaScript probably does allow it, although I haven't tested it ... :)

Comment: @ajb JavaScript does allow it. In fact, JavaScript would allow you to declare a variable in an `if(false)` and even use the variable _before_ that declaration!

Comment: @Daniel, that's because JavaScript has no block scope and applies variable hoisting. http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Java specification says that an `if-then-else` statement is of the following form:

```
IfThenElseStatement:
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement
```

Where `Statement` and `StatementNoShortIf` can be various things including blocks (code surrounded with braces), assignments (to already declared variables), other if statements etc.

Of note is that declaration statements (e.g. `int a;` or `int a = 10;`) are missing from that list, thus you get a compilation error.

For the full list, you can read the Java specification here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

Comment: This should be enough to answer the question, just a little bit surprise for a c++ programmer with this kind of error.

Comment: And with the answer in 'A single-line loop with a mandatory pair of braces in Java' should make it clear enough to the question.

Comment: What does `NoShortIf` refer to?

Comment: @Navin The _NoShortIf_ is to prevent situation with nested if statements where a reader of the code cannot easily decide (or might get confused) to which if an else branch belongs to. This is explained in [section 14.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Nifty!

Answer (score 20):

Lets analyze what your first code example would mean for the language design

```
if(condition)
    int a = 10;
else
    int b = 20;
```

Either it means that depending on the condition we have defined `a` or `b`. As we don't know which branch was taken, how do we use either `a` or `b` after the if-statement? We can't (and if we could that would probably result in strange bugs).

So as language designers we decide that `a` and `b` are not visible outside their respective branches to avoid these weird bugs. But as a block-less branch can only have a single statement, we have declared `a` (or `b`) only to be immediately unreachable/unusable again, so doing that makes no sense. Therefor we decide that a variable declaration is only allowed with a block. A block can have multiple statements, so variables declared in that block can be used by those other statements.

The designers of Java probably applied similar reasoning, so they decided to only allow declaration in a block. This is done through the definition of `if` ([JLS 14.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9)):

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement

IfThenElseStatement:
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement

IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf:
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else StatementNoShortIf
```

`Statement` ([JLS 14.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5))

```
Statement:
    StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
    ...

StatementNoShortIf:
    StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
    ...

StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
    Block
    ...
```

`Block` ([JLS 14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2)):

```
Block:
    { [BlockStatements] }

BlockStatements:
    BlockStatement {BlockStatement}

BlockStatement:
    LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
    ClassDeclaration
    Statement
```

And `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement` ([JLS 14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)), which repeats that it can only occur within a immediately enclosing block:

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block. Local variable declaration statements may be intermixed freely with other kinds of statements in the block.

Answer (score 13):

[JLS-14.4. Local Variable Declaration Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) reads (in part),

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block.

And

[JLS-14.9. If Statmenets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9)

> Otherwise, execution continues by making a choice based on the resulting value:
>
> If the value is true, then the contained Statement is executed; the if-then statement completes normally if and only if execution of the Statement completes normally.
>
> If the value is false, no further action is taken and the if-then statement completes normally.

However, [JLS-14.5. Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) doesn't include variable declaration.

Defining two different variables within the scope of a single-statement block (containing just the variable definitions) makes them both unreachable. I think you'd have better luck with a ternary expression

```
int a = (condition) ? 10 : 20;
```

**or**

```
int a;
if (condition)
    a = 10;
else
    a = 20;
```

**or**

```
int a;
if (condition) {
    a = 10;
} else {
    a = 20;
}
```

Note that the variable `a` is then initialized to a value based on the `condition` and it is reachable after that statement.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment _"So your first example creates a block for int a which terminates the if block (and thus your else has no matching if)."_ The reason is the definition of statement and block in the JLS

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is right.  The error has nothing to do with the `else`.  If you take out the `else` part you still get an error.

Comment: @Mark Edited. Thanks for your input, do you think it reads better now?

Comment: And if it were allowed, how would you reach it? Hence, I think, why it *isn't* allowed.

Comment: You are right that reachability is probably the reason for the syntax, but the reason for the error is the actual syntax of Java as described in the JLS.

Comment: I removed my earlier comment, you are entirely right with your last edit; I was approaching it too much from the syntax point of view, and not from the reasons for that syntax.

Comment: These examples `if... int a = ... else int a = ...` doesn't match the question. The Question is `if... int a =... else int b =...`

Comment: @WernerCD Read the rest of the answer. Such a variable would never be reachable.

Answer (score 6):

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block. Local variable declaration statements may be intermixed freely with other kinds of statements in the block.

Read this 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4

Comment: Except that the second version does compile

Comment: @JuanMendes The second version is immediately contained in a block.

Comment: yes that is the reason

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I guess my question is: Isn't the first one also contained by a block (outside of the if)?

Comment: @JuanMendes No, not **immediately**. See the [answer by Elliot Frisch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27624603/466862) or [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27624783/466862), which describe it in more detail

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you cannot declare variables conditionally.

- When you don't have braces, you're trying to declare a variable conditionally in the outer scope, that's not allowed.
- When you add the braces, you're creating the variables in that local scope (which are not allowed to be used outside of those braces)

Comment: I know this is probably not accurate, I'd love for someone to explain what the problem with the answer is.

Comment: this answer is helpful to me.

Comment: I think your guess is just.... you know... a guess. Other answers provide documentation and the exact 'why' of this behaviour.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna And your comment did not explain what the actual  problem was. The answers that are here are extremely technical, I've written a layman's explanation as to why the designers of Java may have chosen to implement it this way.

Comment: @Juan You have expressed your **opinion** instead of answering the question. You are probably right and I agree with you, but this isn't the answer the OP was looking for.